# How to use EditText instead Fragment for AutoComplete?

Tags: android, google-maps

I use this code to get the adress.

I want to use simple element like EditText as Field and no Fragment. means, if I click on the EditText, the autocomplete popup window should be called, like below

I need 2 fields (field1 adress home, field2 for adress office as example)

Where should I change the code ?

```
txt_lat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_lat);
    txt_lon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_lon);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_anno_add_adress);



    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .build();


    final PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment )
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);





    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.i("TAG", "Place: " + place.getName());
            LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();

            txt_lat.setText(String.valueOf(latLng.latitude));
            txt_lon.setText(String.valueOf(latLng.longitude));
            editText.setText(place.getName());

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            loc_lat=String.valueOf(latLng.latitude);
            loc_lon=String.valueOf(latLng.longitude);
            loc_adress=place.getName().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i("TAG", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

[image]

I need perhaps only the search Icon of AutoComplete (I do not need the Textfield, because i want to use my EditTexts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried AutoCompleteTextView instead of normal EditText

[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html)